# Importing spreadsheet data into MySQL database and building lookup table links on the fly based on discrete fields in each spreadsheet row

Tags: mysql, excel

I have received a spreadsheet with hundreds of thousands of rows containing records of patient visits ("encounters") for a large medical practice. For each visit, a doctor has identified up to twelve diagnoses (columns **diag1**-**diag12**) for the patient using an industry standard code (**ICD10**). Over time, most patients have visited the doctor more than once, identified by the date of service (**dos**), therefore a patient (uniquely identified by their medical record number) may have several rows in the spreadsheet, each with multiple diagnoses codes associated with the specific visit.

I would like to import all of this information into a PHP-based, patient-centric care management database application (MySQL-based) where I can easily access a list of all diagnoses for each patient, rolled-up together from their past visits but I am not sure of the best way to go about structuring things and subsequently importing the data.

Given that there are currently more than 70000 specific ICD10 codes in the industry, I was thinking that I should build an ICD10 code table and, for each patient, define a 1-to-many link between each patient and their associated diagnostic codes. While that sounds logical to me, it is unclear to me how I can easily import the data (in CSV format) while building the ICD10 code links "on-the-fly and, in turn, form the proper SQL (based on the recommended approach) to yield the desired result.

A snippet of the spreadsheet data (depicting 4 visits by 2 different patients) looks like this:

| mrn | dos | diag1 | diag2 | diag3 | diag4 | diag5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-04-12 | R06.00 | I50.9 | I48.91 |  |  |
| 123 | 2023-04-13 | R06.00 | R77.8 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 2023-07-21 | R06.00 | I50.9 | E78.5 | I48.91 |  |
| 456 | 2022-05-05 | Z95.0 | I77.9 |  |  |  |

For the spreadsheet data snippet shown above, I would like to bring up the patient identified by medical record number (**mrn**) "123" and see that they have the following diagnoses: **R06.00**, **I50.9**, **I48.91**, **R77.8**, **E78.5**.

If I was building this database from scratch without regard to existing historical data, I believe I understand how to assign links tying a patient to one or more ICD10 codes. Where I am beating my head against the wall is how to go about importing historical data from a spreadsheet where the ICD10 codes are explicitly attached to each record (and often duplicated between visits) and build a single record in the database for each patient pointing to one or more diagnostic codes in the ICD10 table (removing any duplicate references as well).

Comment: "define a 1-to-many link between each patient and their associated diagnostic codes" diagnoses change, right?  So that link should be between dos and diagnostic code?  Regardless of where the relationship lives - an mrn or a dos - I think the next question is, do you feel like you can enumerate the ICD10 codes so you can store a complete list, or would it be better to simply insert what you got into the codes table with an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICAT KEY UPDATE` ?

Comment: Erik

Reply #1: 
Thanks for the thoughtful questions. As our care management services firm exclusively deals with medical practices having patients with chronic conditions, it is unlikely that their diagnoses will change/go away - in fact, it is highly likely that each patient's list of diagnoses will only grow over time (we focus almost exclusively on seniors on Medicare).

Lloyd

Comment: Erik
Reply #2:

With respect to the ICD10 code, I thought about doing precisely what you suggest but I already have a table of all 70000 codes and related code descriptions (I downloaded a CSV listing of all the codes from CMS.gov and imported them into a table) so I'd prefer to read the list of each patient's diagnoses and link to the corresponding entries in code table if at all possible.

Lloyd

Comment: For actually retrieving the value from the ICD10 database, you can do a sub-select on the 1 to many insert `insert into doagnoses set ... icd10_code_id=(select icd10_code_id from icd10_codes where code = "R06.00")`.  If that's not performant enough, you can CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE with an index on  icd10_code and add an index on icd10_codes.code and then you can `insert into select from`   a join of the icd10 codes and the temporary table.